# A shop and marketplace for selling/buying currencies

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to find a way to do a shop for currencies. That means people can sell one currency and buy the other in return.
In fact this is an online version of an exchange agent.
So far I looked at currency as a product that users can post their own currency to sell using the commerce marketplace. 
So if the default currency is USD, then they can sell GBP and get USD which is ok.
But if they want to buy GBP and sell USD (default currency) then the default currency for that product need to be GBP, as they need to collect GBP which I don't know if such thing is possible!!

The second solution that I though can be possible:
If users in the marketplace be able to post a product to buy, and other users can see this product but with "sell" button instead of "buy", so they can sell their own product if they have it!

Do you have any suggestion for doing such shop or do you have any solution for these 2 scenario that I have in mind?

Hope this make sense and you can help.

Thanks in advance for any help.